# Textview Padding Changes When Position Changes in Listview

Tags: android, listview, textview

I am trying to create a listview item with an imageview to the right of a textview.. lets say if the text was 3 lines i want the text of the first 2 lines to begin after the image view with some padding.. and the third line to be at the bottom of the image with no padding..

I used this code in my list adapter to do this..

```
    TextView commenterName = (TextView) row
            .findViewById(R.id.commenter_name);
    commentText = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv);
    ImageView commenterPhoto = (ImageView) row
            .findViewById(R.id.commenterPhoto);
    Display display = ((WindowManager) row.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    FlowTextHelper.tryFlowText(commentsArray.get(pos).getComment(),
            commenterPhoto, commentText, display, 0);
    commenterName.setText(commentsArray.get(pos).getCommenter());
    commentText.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.Black));
    commentText.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

this working fine.. but when scrolling the list view the text loses its padding and get over the image and out of the screen..

**UPDATE:**
This was the part causing the problem.. i put the else condition to set the default photo but the problem still exist..

```
String path = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, url.length());
    sd = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + Constants.user_images_path + path);

    if (sd.exists()) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = null;
        try {
            //File filePath = context.getFileStreamPath(url);
            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(sd);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 4;
            thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fi, null, options);
            if(thumbnail != null)
                holder.commenterPhoto.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            else
                holder.commenterPhoto.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.commenter_default);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("getThumbnail() on internal storage", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I don't know why this is happening.. Can you help me please?

Comment: Please provide your ListAdapter Code in full. Looks like something is not quite right in the getView() method please provide this.

Comment: why are you setting so much property in java when it can be easily applied in xml??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful with if...else blocks inside the getView() method in the adapter. If you set the background color in red of a LinearLayout inside an if statement you should put the "original" color in the else statement. This is caused by the ListView recycling views. You can see it better explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14108676/3540370)

Answer (score 1):

OK.. I solved the problem by setting my imageView background in the condition of convertview in my getView() method before setting the tag of my holder.. just like this:

```
    View row = convertView; 

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = infalInflater.inflate(resource, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.commentText = (TextView) row.findViewById (R.id.tv);
        holder.commenterPhoto = (ImageView) row.findViewById (R.id.commenterPhoto);
        holder.commenterName = (TextView) row.findViewById (R.id.commenter_name);
        holder.date = (TextView) row.findViewById (R.id.date);
        holder.show = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.show);

        String path = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, url.length());
        sd = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + Constants.user_images_path + path);

        Bitmap thumbnail = null;

        if (sd.exists()) {
            try {

                //File filePath = context.getFileStreamPath(url);
                FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(sd);
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 4;
                thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fi, null, options);
                if(thumbnail != null)
                    holder.commenterPhoto.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                else
                    holder.commenterPhoto.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.commenter_default);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("getThumbnail() on internal storage", ex.getMessage());
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "No Image Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        row.setTag(holder); 
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an "else" in the if(sd.exist()) block. I have supposed that this code is in getView().

Comment: I tried this already.. it didn't work :( And yes, this code is in getView();